# Постоянный рендер одного объекта на сцене в Unity

Tags: unity3d, камера, render

Всем добрый день! Буду крайне благодарен за помощь в решении ситуации.

У камеры имеется область видимости. Объекты, выходящие за её предел - не отображаются. Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли каким-либо образов сделать так, чтобы все объекты подчинялись этому правилу, а один конкретный - отображался всегда, вне зависимости от нахождения в области видимости камеры.

Конкретный пример: все объекты находятся на сцене и должный отображаться тогда, когда попадают в поле видимости игрока. Облака же должный отображаться всегда, вне зависимости от нахождение, относительно области видимости. Т.к. облака для реалистичности - находятся далеко от остальных объектов и выходят за рамки видимости камеры ( В дальность ).

Comment: [Render Object at any Distance?](https://forum.unity.com/threads/render-object-at-any-distance.752948/). Отвечает сотрудник Unity и как можно догадаться, для этого нужно совмещать два рендера. Проще сделать облака по нормальному.

Answer (score 0):

Облака и небо обычно реализовую через технику skydome - один большой объект на который натянута текстура неба с облаками.

Если вы все же хотите заставить юнити отрисовывать объект даже не нарисовав ни одного пикселя то вам нужно обмануть FrustumCulling, [тут есть пример как это можно сделать](https://discussions.unity.com/t/disable-frustum-culling/11018)

Помимо этого, вы можете в скрипте нарисовать вручную необходимый меш с необходимым вам материалом с помощью  [этого API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Graphics.DrawMesh.html)